# How to resolve a dependency at runtime with parameters?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I have a simple interface `ICloudStorageRepository` which is implemented by two concrete classes:

```
public class AWSStorageRepository : ICloudStorageRepository
{
   private readonly IS3Client _client;
   public AWSStorageRepository(AWSCredentials credentials)
   {
       _client = new AWSStorageFactory(credentials).Create();
   }
}
```

and:

```
public class AzureStorageRepository : ICloudStorageRepository
{
   private readonly IAzureClient _client;
   public AzureStorageRepository(AzureCredentials credentials)
   {
       _client = new AzureStorageFactory(credentials).Create();
   }
```

}

then in my client I have a service:

```
public class CloudService
{
    public CloudService(ICloudStorageRepository repository)
    ....

    public Task<ListFiles> GetFiles(GetFilesInput input)
    {
         if(input.Provider == 'aws')
           resolve with AWSStorageRepository
         if(input.Provider == 'azure')
           resolve with AzureStorageRepository
    }
}
```

I'm using Castle Windsor as container, I'll get the credentials at runtime within the input parameter, just to use once, so I need to pass it as the argument dependency.

How can i do it in runtime without registering it on container?

Comment: `constructor(AWSCredentials credentials)`? That doesn't sound like c#

Comment: sorry it was a typo

Comment: Register and resolve an implementation by name https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21752389/castle-windsor-how-to-resolve-by-name (other IoC containers have better support for this)